# Performance Counter : "Database Cache % Hit"

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I used this bit of code to retrieve the available performance counters on the machine I want to monitor:

```
        var allCounters = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
        foreach (var category in PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories("machine-name"))
        {
            var names = category.GetInstanceNames();
            if (names.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    allCounters.AddRange(category.GetCounters(name));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allCounters.AddRange(category.GetCounters());
            }
        }
```

I found a counter which I want to monitor: `Database Cache % Hit`. Its does not have any instance names so I just get it this way:

```
new PerformanceCounter("Database", "Database Cache % Hit", null, "machine-name"); //null or "" for the third argument
```

This works until I call the `NextValue` method on it, which raises an `InvalidOperationException` :

```
Counter is not single instance, an instance name needs to be specified.
```

I tried putting the name of the SQL Server DB Name I want to monitor but it does not work either (it fails during instanciation instead).

How can I use this performance counter in my C# application?

Comment: Type `perfmon.exe` in _run_ and see how many instance under your `Database --> Database Cache % Hit` counter. It is clearly more than one.

Comment: on my computer, yes. on the remote machine, nope :/ there is no instance name showing up in perfmon. maybe the counter itself is broken, because perfoman can't even monitor it. I should add that the remote machine is a VM hosted on HyperV, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, "Database" counters group has nothing to do with SQL server. It is part of [ESENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961947.aspx) infrastructure.

For SQL server statistics look for `MSSQL$instance_name` counters. Probably you are looking for Buffer Manager cache hit ratio, however there are other caches (like query plan cache).

Also you may want to query statistics directly from `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` view, bypassing this excessive windows counters layer...

Comment: Thanks for the info! However I cannot find any category named `MSSQL` nor `SQLServer` (I see them in the view but not in perfmon nor in my code) : ran `lodctr /R` on the remote, didn't help. I guess there's something wrong with the HyperV somewhere.

Comment: ...and even HyperV blesses you to query data directly )